# If-Else statement not working within a while loop

Tags: c#, database, if-statement

I have an issue where I'm trying to create a login form, however the else statement seems to be ignored.

How can I write this code extract so that a message box is shown when the incorrect data is put into the text boxes? (All databases are set up correctly).

```
try
{
    sc.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from StudentRecords where ID = '" + txtBoxUsername.Text + "' ", sc); //where ID = '" + txtBoxUsername.Text + "' and DOB = '" + textBoxPassword.Text + "'
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        if (txtBoxUsername.Text == (myReader["ID"].ToString()) && textBoxPassword.Text == (myReader["DOB"].ToString()))
        {
            LoginSuccessForm loginfrm = new LoginSuccessForm();
            loginfrm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (txtBoxUsername.Text != (myReader["ID"].ToString()) || textBoxPassword.Text != (myReader["DOB"].ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password and/or Username", "Error");
            break;
        }

    }
    sc.Close();
}
```

I have tried putting the messagebox outside of the while loop and that doesn't work in the desired way. (Following the try method is a catch, I didn't include it to save space).

In saying that, it seems to only pick up the first user in the database too.
Any clues or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: You should *really* be using parameterized queries - you are vulnerable to sql injection here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however SQL injections are not something I'll be concerned about as this is simply a University project.

Comment: Not saying this is the problem, but you can replace your `else if (txt...` with a simple `else`. The check in the if is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the observation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the results, since you're only expecting one row max. I would do it this way:

```
using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand()) {
   cmd.CommandText = "select 1 from Students where Username=.. and Password= ..";
   if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null) {
      // username and password matched a user
   }
   else {
      // no match 
   }
}
```

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns the first column of the first row, or null if there was no result.

If this was a real project, you'd need to use `SqlParameters` to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities and also look at hashing/salting rather than storing plain-text passwords.